# Can I login in a website directly through browser if I have the cookie session id?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies, browser, session-cookies

I have a project in mind where I need to automatically login to a website using the cookie session id.

I know I can generate a cookie through the session ID in php or python for example, but I don't know if I can login directly in the webbrowser without having something else storing the cookie first .

Is it feasible to login in browser directly without any other steps like using curl in PHP and if so how can it be accomplished ?

Thanks

Comment: mentioning of firefox is irrelevant here. There are use cases when website would be willing to login user without entering login and password. Such use cases could be "forgot password" or "unsubscribe" functions. Just give user an URL with short-term login token embedded into URL. Could you please extend description of your question to state your use case?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I want to be able to automatically login in another browser different from the original one after the username as provided their session id, don't really know how to provide much more relevant data to what I'm trying to accomplish .

Once the user provides their session ID I want to use that to automatically login the user in a different browser on my side. 

Like I stated in OP I realize it's possible to get a cookie by doing a Curl request with the session id but my goal here is to achieve the same just via browser and without needing to create a cookie beforehand .

Comment: Anyone can shed some light on this please?

Comment: Take a look at [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Please edit your question and describe your use case otherwise you will get wrong answers/solution. What about server-side code? Are you developer who is responsible for implementation of such impersonation feature and you can extend server side code? if you can extend server-side code then your task can be solved with couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A copy of the cookie containing the session ID has to be placed in the browser's cookie jar.

- You can't do that with an HTTP response from a different origin.
- You can't do that with a browser on a different system

You *might* be able to do it with a browser on the same system as the program by directly editing the data store that the browser stores cookies in. If the browser is already running it might not update its in-memory records of the cookies though.

It's possible that the server is implementing anti-session hijacking techniques such as associating the session id with a particular IP address or uses other fingerprinting techniques such as examining the User-Agent. If so, you'd need to ensure these match too.